# What is Global data (Has the term become stretched)?

Tags: language-agnostic, global-variables

What exactly is global data?

This may seem like a very rudimentary question but the reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering has the term become stretched over time - i.e it dosn't just apply to data in the "Global" namespace (in c++) or a variable that is available in every scope.

So, what do you consider to be global data?

Comment: What's the purpose of this question? You can easily find a definition for a given language. I don't see the point.

Comment: @silky I'm curious if the term has become stretched over time to apply to contexts that I'm not aware of

Comment: But why? Who cares? What would you do with the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree David, *global* can quite often mean different things to different people in different languages!

Personally I hate globals which are truly global, i.e. available to everything, everywhere.  The greater the restriction of a scopes' variable, generally the better.

The scope of the information often has to be open to lots of functions within a module, this is OK, but should be limited where required.  These I would define a *module globals* or *local globals*.

Variables which are shared between modules through a defined interface and **only included as required** are OK-ish, but data passed back and forth (or pointers to data) from/to functions are the best.

Of course, this is all my personal opinion in my native language (C) and might not agree with everyone's opinion!

Answer (score 1):

Global data is a variable that can be put in any local scope (i.e. of a function) without passing it as a parameter or class attribute.

In some languages you need a `global` or `extern` keyword to import it, in others it enters the function's scope automatically.